# Connect to Azure PostgreSQL using Azure Data Studio with SSL enabled

Tags: postgresql-11, postgresql-12, azure-postgresql

When i try to connect to Azure PostgreSQL with SSL enabled using Azure Data Studio , with SSL Mode=Verfiy-full, i get below error

root certificate file "C:\Users\mstechie\AppData\Roaming/postgresql/root.crt" does not exist
Either provide the file or change sslmode to disable server certificate verification.

i dont want to disable SSL mode , but want to use SSL.
[image]Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of database being Azure PostgreSQL PaaS and if we choose SSL mode = disable , it throws an error saying SSL required , since SSL is enabled by default on server. Of course we can disable it , but not recommended.

if we choose the SSL mode = Allow ,(instead of Verify-full) , it does not ask for certificate.

if we choose SSL mode = Require or SSL mode = Prefer , then also it does not ask for certificate and connects properly.

if we choose SSL mode = Verify-CA  or SSL mode = Verify-full , then it requires certificate and we have to give the path of the certificate as shown below
[image]